How to secure sensitive variables in external GitLab CI templates?
I have:

20 Java services stored on GitLab repositories
1 template repository which stores CI/CD scripts/rules/variables

Service repositories:

have a .gitlab-ci.yml file which includes CI from template repository:
include:
  - project: my-project/cicd/templates
    ref: master
    file: /jobs/.java-ci.yaml


run on any protected (master/develop) / non-protected (feature/bugfix) branches

use JFROG_CREDENTIALS (masked/protected) to push in artifactory

use KUBE_CONFIG (masked/protected) to deploy on k8s cluster


How can I avoid the following code from being run with bad intentions in service repositories?
include:
  - project: cicd/templates
    ref: master
    file: /jobs/.java-ci.yaml

# BAD INTENTION ADDED
hack:
  stage: .pre
  image: any-image
  script:
    - echo "$JFROG_CREDENTIALS" | base64 > hack-jfrog-credentials.txt
    - cat hack-jfrog-credentials.txt
    - echo "$KUBE_CONFIG" | base64 > hack-kube-config.txt
    - cat hack-kube-config.txt

Moreover, to make the include work, each user of the pipeline needs access as REPORTER on the template repository where all sensitive variables are clearly named.
Is there a way to secure the template repository while letting team members run pipelines from external templates?
I have tried:

protected branches on template repository, not working as expected
CODEOWNERS but it works only for merge requests
triggers between service repository pipeline and templates repository pipeline, but this is an anti pattern

